# Adding user to group on creation in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication

I'm looking to add a User to a group only if a field of this User is specified as 'True' once the User is created. Every User that is created would have a 'UserProfile' associated with it. Would this be the correct way to implement such a thing?

models.py:

```
def add_group(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        sender = UserProfile
        if sender.is_in_group:
            from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
            g = Group.objects.get(name='Some Group')
            g.user_set.add(sender)

post_save.connect(add_group, sender=UserProfile)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of post_save of UserProfile you should register for User.

Comment: not that it makes a difference, but why are you overwriting the sender ?

Answer (score 5):

Another option is using a `post_save` signal

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

def add_user_to_public_group(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """Post-create user signal that adds the user to everyone group."""

    try:
        if created:
            instance.groups.add(Group.objects.get(pk=settings.PUBLIC_GROUP_ID))
    except Group.DoesNotExist:
        pass

post_save.connect(add_user_to_public_group, sender=User)
```

Only trouble you will have is if you use a fixture ... (hence the DoesNotExists .. )

Comment: I prefer to use the `post_save` signal, but I need to be able to check whether this Boolean field is marked as true before I add the User to the group. My `UserProfile` model has a `OneToOneField` relationship with the 'User' and is created when a new `User` is saved, so I had thought that the `sender` should be `UserProfile`. Apparently, I'm wrong on that, which is fine, but I still need to be able to perform the check before adding the 'User' to the group.

Comment: Using decorators would be `from django.dispatch import receiver` 
 `@receiver(post_save, sender=User)`  `def add_user_to_public_group(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):`  instead of using `post_save.connect(add_user_to_public_group, sender=User)`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # `save` method of your `User` model

    # if user hasnt ID - is creationg operation
    created = self.id is None
    super(YourModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    # after save user has ID
    # add user to group only after creating
    if created:
        # adding to group here
```