# Django - make admin fields invisible to some users

Tags: python, django

TL;DR I'd like to be able to disable certain models per-user in /admin view.

Specifically: I'm looking to make admin models invisible to some staff users, so that they can have a sort of customized dashboard. There's all sorts of fields that change how to present, search, query, etc. models based on whatever you want, but I can't find anything to allow me to determine whether or not to even show models on the /admin page without resorting to blacklisting individual permissions (of which there are hundreds), and I'd like to be able to make some models only available to superusers and not staff.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you put django users into django groups and give that permission to that group instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't give them superuser rights. Superuser means they have all rights automatically, which isn't what you want.

Then add edit, add, delete rights for the models they are allowed to edit, add and delete. You can create a group that you give these rights to, then add the users to that group.

If a user doesn't have add, edit or delete rights to a model, the model isn't shown in the admin.

Comment: That would be excellent! Unfortunately http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41574022/adding-user-to-group-on-save-in-django-1-9

Comment: Hmm don't see a solution for that one yet, and don't have time to dive into it now...

Comment: if you did, I'd wait 'til tomorrow and award you a bounty on it, which I will be placing anyway if I don't get an answer